# GCM notification not working (GoogleCloudMessaging)

Tags: google-cloud-messaging

I have a strange problem with GCM using `GoogleCloudMessaging`, where the notifications work at the beginning but somehow stop working after some time (roughly an hour or so).

Another thing, whenever I register with `GoogleCloudMessaging.getInstance(context).register(SENDER_ID);` i get the call in the `onReceive()` of my '`WakefulBroadcastReceiver`' which contains `REGISTRATION_ID` in bundle extras. Is this a common thing and should I just ignore this?

I have followed the tutorial from here [Implementing GCM client](https://developer.android.com/google/gcm/client.html).

**EDIT:** The problem was with a library called Localytics, which was also handling Push notifications. Nothing related to GCM setup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT: The problem was with a library called Localytics, which was also handling Push notifications. Nothing related to GCM setup.

Answer (score 2):

Every GCM message has expired date, the message might have expired, or the device is not connected, and messages are not real time.

GCM uses broadcast receiver to deliver messages in following steps:
1. onClick() calls gcm.send()
2. onReceive() method in broadcast receiver triggered
3. the method handles GCM messages

A **WakefulBroadcastReceiver** is a special type of broadcast receiver that takes care of creating and managing a partial wake lock for your app. It passes off the work of processing the GCM message to a Service (typically an IntentService), while ensuring that the device does not go back to sleep in the transition. If you don't hold a wake lock while transitioning the work to a service, you are effectively allowing the device to go back to sleep before the work completes. The net result is that the app might not finish processing the GCM message until some arbitrary point in the future, which is not what you want.

However, using WakefulBroadcastReceiver is **not a requirement**. If your app does not require a service, you can use a regular BroadcastReceiver.

According to the GCM documentation, *after registering, the app calls storeRegistrationId() to store the registration ID in shared preferences for future use. This is just one way of persisting a regID*. So the registration_id is good for data persistence.